# Recursive domain and subdomain comparaison?

Tags: php, regex, for-loop, compare

I want compare a single domain with different rules.

Example cases:

I have `sub.domain.tld` and I want compare with:

- `*` - Any domain or subdomain.
- `*.domain.tld` Any subdomain of **domain.tld**.
- `*.sub.domain.tld` - Any subdomain of **sub.domain.tld**.
- `*.sub.*.tld` - Any sub domain of **sub.**, and any domain with dot **tld**.
- `*.*.*.*` - Require **two any subdomain** of any domain with any dot.
- `domain.*` - Any TLD(gTLD, ccTLD, sTLD, etc)

If I compare, I expect result like:

- `*` - `true`
- `*.domain.tld` - `true`
- `*.sub.domain.tld` - `false`
- `*.sub.*.tld` - `false`
- `*.*.*.*` - `false`
- `domain.*` - `false`

I think in Regexp, but I don't have idea how start with it.
I try escaping `*` with `preg_quote` and compare, but only work with first and second example.

Answer (score 2):

You should indeed use `preg_quote`, but then replace the `\*` in the result with `.*?`, which is the regex way to say: any characters, but not more than necessary.

You could use this function:

```
function matchDomain($mask, $domain) {
    $mask = '/^' . str_replace('\\*', '.*?', preg_quote($mask)) . '$/';
    return preg_match($mask, $domain) == 1;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
var_dump(matchDomain('*.*.*.tld', 'test.sub.domain.tld')); // true
var_dump(matchDomain('*.*.domain.*', 'test.sub.domain.tld')); // true
```